# Need to group dynamic data from Firestore to Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to be able to pull constantly changing data from my DB (cloud firestore) into my flutter app in their own groups.

My current setup is as follows:

DB - Contents(collection)/Document(with fields)
 One of these fields in the document is 'Type' and I will have everything grouped into a certain type (ex: Bike, Car, Truck) on the homepage

My code is as follows:

---

```
 Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ExpansionTile(
          title: Text( document['Type'].toString()), //This shows Bike, Car, Truck
          children: <Widget>[
      Text(
      document[ 'FullVN' ].toString( )) // This shows Full Vehicle Name
            ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.white, //This gives the selected expansion contents color
      ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black12, //This give the expansion title color
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text( 'Area Contents' )
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection( 'Contents' ).snapshots( ),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text( 'Loading...' );
            return ListView.builder(
              itemExtent: 80.0,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  _buildListItem( context, snapshot.data.documents[index] ),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
class UnknownRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const UnknownRoute({Key key, this.onUnknownRoute}) : super( key: key );

  final RouteFactory onUnknownRoute;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return null;
  }

}
```

---

What I have tried:

I have tried several DB setups including Collection(Contents)/document(Type)/Collection(Cars,Bikes,Trucks)/Documents(fields including data needed)

I have also tried to call the sub collection/document for the expansion tile as title: Text( collection/document['Type'].toString()) in hopes of grouping. (not both at the same time of course)

Current reality:
My data is returning as follows:

Bikes
 - Bike 1
Bikes
 - Bike 2
Cars
 - Car 1, etc. My data is there, just not grouped

My goal:

I would like to see the data pulled like:
Bikes (title of expansion tile)
 - Bike 1
 - Bike 2
Cars (another title of a separate expansion tile)
 - Car 1
 - Car 2
Trucks (another title of a separate expansion tile) etc....
*** As new 'Types' get added (such as boats) they will populate as another expansion tile

JSON DB is as follows:

```
{
  "Collection3": {
    "Bikes": {
      "Category": "Bikes",
      "Items": {
        "ID1": {
          "BrandName": "Kawasaki",
          "Description": "1500 Vulcan Nomad"
        },
        "ID2": {
          "BrandName": "Honda",
          "Description": "750 Shadow ACE"
        }
      }
    },
    "Cars": {
      "Category": "Cars",
      "Items": {
        "ID1": {
          "BrandName": "Dodge",
          "Description": "Dodge Challenger"
        },
        "ID2": {
          "BrandName": "Ford",
          "Description": "Mustang GT Cobra"
        }
      }
    },
    "Trucks": {
      "Category": "Trucks",
      "Items": {
        "ID1": {
          "BrandName": "Chevy",
          "Description": "Chevy Silvarado"
        },
        "ID2": {
          "BrandName": "Ford",
          "Description": "Ford F-150"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share a json example of your collection?

Comment: Added it through an Edit